# Javascript framework to track detailed user behavior?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

Is there a Javascript framework to track detailed user behaviors on web page?

For example, like users clicking which link to enter which page, whether user type data into the input control etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a popular service named [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript#js) that does what you want.

> "Mixpanel is an advanced analytics service that helps improve web and
>   mobile applications by tracking how users interact & engage with
>   them."

Sending data only takes 1 line of code per event. You can easily track any kind of user interaction - such as button clicks, menu usage, or user signups - with just a little bit of code.

**Here's an example of tracking button clicks using MixPanel**:

```
$("#my_button").click(function() {
    // This sends us an event every time a user clicks the button
    mixpanel.track("Button clicked"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use google analysis? such as event track.
[google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)